Is there a way for type aliases to depend on incomplete types in CRTP?
Take a simple CRTP example:
template <class Target>
struct StaticCallable
{
    static auto StaticCall()
    {
        return Target().Call();
    }

    using ReturnType = decltype(Target().Call());
};

struct StaticCallableInt : StaticCallable<StaticCallableInt>
{
    int Call() { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    StaticCallableInt::ReturnType val;
    val = StaticCallableInt::StaticCall();
}

StaticCallable<> is instantiated with StaticCallableInt which at that point is not a complete type. For StaticCall(), that's okay. Evaluation is deferred until the function is called, and by then StaticCallableInt will be a complete type.
For the ReturnType alias, though, that's a problem, because it's evaluated on the spot, and it needs StaticCallableInt to have Call() declared by then. With this need unfulfilled, this code fails to compiles.
Are there any good techniques for type aliases in CRTP? A solution that pops out to me is to use a helper class for all the class details StaticCallable<> needs:
struct CallableInt
{
    int Call() { return 2; }
};

struct StaticCallableInt : StaticCallable<CallableInt> {};

Are there any other ways to have type aliases depend on incomplete types, possibly by deferring the alias's evaluation?

You can add another level of indirection by putting the alias in an internal struct.
This will defer the evaluation of the alias:
#include <iostream>

template <class Target>
struct StaticCallable
{
    static auto StaticCall()
    {
        return Target().Call();
    }
    
    // Add this struct, with the type alias inside it:
    struct RetType
    {
        using value = decltype(Target().Call());
    };
};

struct StaticCallableInt : StaticCallable<StaticCallableInt>
{
    int Call() { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    StaticCallableInt::RetType::value val;  // use the type alias
    val = StaticCallableInt::StaticCall();
    std::cout << val;
}

Output:
2

Live demo.

That's smart to use a wrapper class to delay evaluation. Even though the wrapper class means RetVal::type is more verbose than the other solution's RetVal<>, I like how there's no way to misuse this approach, so it works better for my use-case.

@JoshuaMaiche great, happy to help !

You can simply make ReturnType an alias template as shown below:
template <class Target>
struct StaticCallable
{
    static auto StaticCall()
    {
        return Target().Call();
    }

    //now this is a template 
    template<typename T = Target>
    using RetType = decltype(T().Call()); 
};

struct StaticCallableInt : StaticCallable<StaticCallableInt>
{
    int Call() { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    StaticCallableInt::RetType<> val;      
    val = StaticCallableInt::StaticCall(); //works now
}

Working demo

Really nifty solution! I tried doing something similar with T = void and using Target directly, but that didn't work. I'm guessing using T makes it a dependent name, deferring the call of decltype until after StaticCallableInt is a complete type. Seems like a handy trick!

@JoshuaMaiche Yes exactly. Using Target directly will result in direct substitution instead of differing the substitution.

I thought about this solution a bit more, and one thing that bugged me was the possibility to misuse RetType<> by passing in an incorrect type. One solution to this (that does need a bit more machinery) is to have a struct that forces the use of a dependent name while not actually using it:
template<typename T, typename> struct PickFirst { using type = T; };
Then, the type can consistently be forced to be Target while still using a dependent name:
using RetType = decltype(typename PickFirst<Target, T>::type().Call());
Example in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Evoc3PrTM

@JoshuaMaiche You can also use SFINAE like template<typename T = Target, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, Target>>> using RetType = decltype(T().Call()); so that no other types are accepted.

@user12002570 RetType<Bob, void> avoids your SFINAE there :p  Need to use enable_if_t<cond, bool> = true or requires or another "stronger" SFINAE technique

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah, requires is best? if c++20 is available.
